# Could not find the IHttpModule if I install it to the GAC cache

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have a simple IHttpModule

```
namespace System.Web.Extensions.Resource
{
    public class MyHttpModule : IHttpModule
    {
        public void Dispose()
        {
        }

        public void Init(HttpApplication context)
        {
            context.PreSendRequestContent += PreSend_RequestContent;
        }

        private void PreSend_RequestContent(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpResponse response = ((HttpApplication)sender).Response;
            response.AddHeader("MyHttpModule", "Running");
        }
    }
}
```

And I installed it to GAC with powershell (No errors at all):

```
$name = "c:\MyHttpModule.dll";

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load('System.EnterpriseServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a');
$publish = New-Object System.EnterpriseServices.Internal.Publish;
$publish.GacInstall($name);

$type = 'System.Web.Extensions.Resource.MyHttpModule,' + [System.Reflection.AssemblyName]::GetAssemblyName($name).FullName;
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\Appcmd.exe add module /name:MyHttpModule /type:"$type"
```

But when I access the IIS site, I got

> Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'MyHttpModule, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

So Windows no longer support installation to GAC cache?

**EDIT**

I've added a strong name and confirmed the assembly is installed to C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\MyHttpModule\v4.0_1.0.0.0__4959579d21f18138.

[image]

Now IIS has a different error

```
 System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Web.Extensions.Resource.MyHttpModule' from assembly 'MyHttpModule, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4959579d21f18138'.
```

But from ILSpy I can see this type is available, so what was wrong then?

[image]

**EDIT again**

It suddenly worked, I've seen the header added by the module. Not sure why, but closing it now.

Comment: Would there be a difference if `MyHttpModule` was strong-named?

Comment: Did you reset IIS after installing in GAC?

Comment: @Sasha Yes, please see my edit

Comment: Why are you putting it in the GAC.  GACing assemblies makes deployment (particularly for a web app) a complete pain.  Put it in a NuGet package and do it the modern way

Comment: @daisy, Is IIS running on your machine, or are you copying the assembly to another machine?

Comment: @Sasha Same machine. I've installed VS2019 on a Windows 2016 server.

Comment: Weird, it suddenly worked ..

Comment: @Ramesh I think running `iisreset` helped, it suddenly worked somehow, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PublicKeyToken is null, which mean the DLL is not signed with a strong name. You need to sign the Dll and then put it to GAC,  please refer the MSDN article [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/install-assembly-into-gac), the article also tells you how to sign it in VS:

Comment: Thanks Matt, now I have a different error, please see my edit